# Access Json Properties

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Json file with the following content in it

```
{"title":"Json 10","body":"lorem","price":"12"}
```

The content is comming from a form, wehere the user can submit this data.

Later I need to give the user the ability to display this data on his website. Therefor I am using a widget. The widget is grabbing the json an put the content inside the restaurant-widget-container div

My Question is: How can I access each property. With this code

```
var jsonp_url = "http://localhost:8000/uploads/json/10_dailydish.json";
       jQuery.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(result) {
        //alert(result.html);
        $('#restaurant-widget-container').html(result.title);

       });
```

to display the content of the json file in my "restaurant-widget-container".

I need to display the title, body and price inside the div. But with the code above I am just display the title.

I also played arround with

```
$('#restaurant-widget-container').append(result.title).append(result.body);
```

This basically works, but I have the feeling that there is a better way.

Comment: what is your restaurant-widget-container for kind of object , and what do you expect to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the keys of your JSON object, than you could iterate over with a simple:

```
for (var k in result) { 
    // This print out the value
    console.log("The value" + result[k]); 
}
```

But if you want to access directly, as you know the keys you want to access to, than you have 2 methods:

```
var v = result["mykey"];
```

This is good if you have the keys as strings in some config variable.

Or more directly:

```
var v = result.mykey;
```

The second part of your question is about emend the HTML with the values using jquery.

Here your code:

> ```
> $('#restaurant-widget-container').append(result.title).append(result.body);
> ```

This just add the strings to the dom element with id *#restaurant-widget-container*.

Here you should design and write your html properly. You could do that directly in your page and then access using jquery to update the values, or using a template engine line handlebars.

The choice depends on the complexity of your case and your flavors.

So you could write a simple html example using just jquery and with an imperative approach.

```
// Reset the current content to avoid concatenation
// of previous results.
$('#restaurant-widget-container').html('');

var $resultTitle = $('<h1></h1>').text(result.title);

var $resultBody = $('<div></div>').html(result.body);

var $resultPrice = $('<span></span>').text('Price: ' + result.price + ' $');

$('#restaurant-widget-container')
    .append($resultTitle)
    .append($resultBody)
    .append($resultPrice);
```

Here is a working example.

```js
$(function() {

function showResults(result) {
    // Reset the current content to avoid concatenation
    // of previous results.
    $('#restaurant-widget-container').html('');

    var $resultTitle = $('<h1></h1>').text(result.title);

    var $resultBody = $('<div></div>').html(result.body);

    var $resultPrice = $('<span></span>').text('Price: ' + result.price + ' $');

    $('#restaurant-widget-container')
        .append($resultTitle)
        .append($resultBody)
        .append($resultPrice);
}
 
  $('button').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    showResults({"title": "My cool title!", "body": "All you need to write goes here...", "price": 123.45});
   });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="restaurant-widget-container">
  </div>
<hr/>
<button>Show</button>
```

Comment: My keys are "title", "body" and "price.  I need to chain them in my restaurant-widget-container div.

Comment: Sorry, I meed some more clues to help you on this. Are you speak about html formatting? Please update your question adding more details about where you want to put the vealues, and why you cant't do it.